# What's the cleanest way to produce a copy of an existing XML file excluding elements that match a couple different XPath expressions?

Tags: xslt, xpath, lxml, xquery

I have two XPath expressions that select items of an XML configuration file that I want to delete, either in place or in a new file.

```
//xsltCustomEngines/field/String[matches(text(),'^(Locally|Clean|Git|Go).*')]/ancestor::xsltCustomEngines

//userEditorVariable-array/userEditorVariable/field/String[matches(text(),'^\$\{(product|use\-gerrit|release|artifact).*') or matches(text(),'\-url\}$')]/ancestor::userEditorVariable
```

My guess is that XQuery, XSLT, or the Python lxml library with XPath support could all be used, but I want the most simple version. I debugged the above XPaths to prove that they select the items I want to strip, including their child elements, but I'm not sure of the scaffolding around these expressions that would be required with these various methods. I have XSLT 3.0, XPath 3.1, and XQuery 3.1 available to use. Can I use an identity transform that somehow filters out these elements?

Comment: If the duplicated you were referred to doesn't help then, to use your shown XPath expressions as match patterns, I think you need to rewrite e.g. `//xsltCustomEngines/field/String[matches(text(),'^(Locally|Clean|Git|Go).*')]/ancestor::xsltCustomEngines` to `<xsl:template match="xsltCustomEngines[field/String[matches(.,'^(Locally|Clean|Git|Go).*')]]"/>`